# Python3 + Discord - Send a message each X seconds

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to create a Discord bot that would automatically send a message each X seconds (every 3 seconds, for example) without any user interaction/command input.

This is the code that I have:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    print("Logged in as:")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print("------")
    channel = bot.get_channel(IDasInteger)
    print("Channel is:")
    print(channel) #Prints None
    get_price.start()

@tasks.loop(seconds=3)
async def get_price():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    channel = bot.get_channel(IDasInteger)
    print("Channel is:")
    print(channel) #Prints None
    await channel.send('Test')

@get_price.before_loop
async def before ():
    print("Before done.")

bot.run('MyTokenHere')
```

The problem is, that when I execute this code, it gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

When I try to print the channel variable it returns None.
The Channel ID is correct - I have copied it directly from Discord app without any alterations to its value.

Any ideas, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting `None` is that `IDasInteger` is not defined (at least in the code you provided. If it is defined in your code then it cannot find the channel and returns `None`. `None` does not have the attribute send and the error is raised.

Change the channel id to the id of a valid channel in your server.

`functions channel = bot.get_channel(790279425633758682)`

Or make sure the `IDasInteger` is returning a valid channel ID

Note: I tested the code with a valid channel id to my server and it worked as intended.

Comment: This was the issue since I used wrong channel ID. Thank you